# Location Pointer and Distance Calculation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to calculate the distance between the current location(by getting latitude,longitude from GPS) and designation (mecca[mosque]) which is fixed. Please anyone guide me.

-Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils

Answer (score 2):

Make use of

```
 [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
```

In your case

```
[currentLocation distanceFromLocation:meccaLocation];
```

Note that this returns the distance in `CLLocationDistance`

Comment: Yes. You are right. But how can we get the current location withhout Using GPS and web services?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786762/current-location-without-using-gps

Answer (score 0):

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Excellent coverage of the subject.

Additional details are in Bowditch's *American Practical Navigator*.

And it may help to know this: 21° 25' 36" N / 39° 49' 34" E

Comment: +1 for a great link. Also, if you need to know the distance with an accuracy better than 0.5%, there's this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae

Comment: And your latitude is off.  http://toolserver.org/~geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Kaaba&params=21_25_21_N_39_49_34_E_type:landmark_scale:2000