# Can we get Location of user with internet on and Location settings disable(GPS OFF)?

Tags: ios, core-location

Ok i think the question is pretty easy to understand. Is it possible to retrieve own Location(coordinate) using CLLocation OR any other method known where Location Settings is turned off from settings, but the phone has internet and cellular connections on.

## EDIT

The link posted didnt solve my query.
I want to know if a user disables Location Service from Settings, then Does CLLocationManager still fetch location data of the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [current location without using gps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786762/current-location-without-using-gps)

Comment: No, `CLLocationManager` will not work if location services are turned off - it would be a total violation of the users' privacy!